# Cannot configure or uninstall AD CS role

Tags: windows-server-2016, active-directory-adcs

We installed the AD Certificate Services role on Windows 2016 Server version 1607. We cannot complete the post deployment configuration. We get the error "Value does not fall within expected range." After doing some digging, I found that it is conflicting with Windows Server Essentials Experience. I cannot remove the AD CS role. Every time I try and remove, I receive the error "The status of the role services on the target machine cannot be determined." I cannot figure out how to get this role removed.

Comment: you may try to use PowerShell `Remove-WindowsFeature -remove -Name AD-Certificate`